# sql if else alternative actions

Tags: sql, oracle, select, if-statement

I have a trigger as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
dummy CHAR(30);

BEGIN

SELECT fooID into dummy
FROM Foo
WHERE FooID = :new.FooID;

IF SQL%FOUND THEN 
    --action 1...
ELSE
    --action 2...
END IF;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'NO DATA');

END;
/
```

I want the trigger to work in a way when the record is found in `Foo` table, then it can do action 1 or otherwise do action 2. but the trigger straight go to `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception when the record in `Foo` table not found.

meaning that, when i testing it, if record found, it do action 1 , if not, it skipped action 2 and go to `NO_DATA_FOUND`, which is not what I want.

I've also tried `ELSIF` on `NOT SQL%FOUND` or omit the exception block but it doesn't work.  I am wondering where is the problem occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could put action do in the "CATCH" part of your exception.

```
BEGIN

SELECT fooID into dummy
FROM Foo
WHERE FooID = :new.FooID;
--action1
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
--action2
END
```

Comment: what if I still have more select statements below that, i might need to have more than 1 `EXCEPTION`

Comment: @HolaAmigos well, yes, sure. You can have as many`BEGIN EXCEPTION END `blocks as you need. But hard to say "just like this" how you should solve this.

Comment: @HolaAmigos you can also have a variable, set a different value if Exception is raised or not , and apply your action after "all catched exceptions" (not sure this is really clear ;)).

Comment: but is it possible to have multiple `BEGIN END` blocks in trigger? it giving me the error: 'Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" ' after my first block

Comment: @HolaAmigos I would say yes (but not sure, hard to say if that's your code problem or a limitation). Anyway, you can call a SP in a trigger if that's a problem.

Comment: You can nest anonymous blocks within the trigger block.  However I would question the design.  Executing multiple SELECT statements whenever the trigger fires is a poor approach.  It will probaby cause performance and/or scaling problems.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus it's my error, sorry. I just found out we need to have another outermost `BEGIN END` block to cover all the blocks used in the trigger. thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

try

```
l_count   BINARY_INTEGER;
...
SELECT count(*)
  INTO l_count
  FROM Foo
 WHERE FooID = :new.FooID
     ;

IF l_count > 0 THEN
    -- action 1
ELSE
    -- action 2
END IF;
-- ...
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
dummy CHAR(30) := NULL; -- initialize your variables ever;

BEGIN

SELECT fooID into dummy
FROM Foo
WHERE FooID = :new.FooID;

IF dummy IS NOT NULL THEN 
    --action 1...
ELSE
    --action 2...
END IF;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'NO DATA');

END;
```